# Harmonic or dummy seasonal model

Tags: time-series, matrix-decomposition, seasonality

Within the BFAST package in R, one of the parameters that it gives is the choice of seasonal model parameter (harmonic, dummy, or none). I understand what none does; However, I didn't really understand the difference between the other two and the reference manual said to read the remote sensing papers. I then looked around the internet and found the first paper on remote sensing, but I couldn't understand it clearly enough as to what the dummy parameter does. I then tried looking for the second remote sensing paper, which talked about the harmonic seasonal parameter, but I couldn’t find the paper. So my question is, what is the difference between harmonic and dummy seasonal model within the BFAST package?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.